# Avoid same object in the existing angular model

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, array-merge

Trying to merge two arrays with some simmilar occurances in two array 
here's what i did

```
var json_dest = [
    {
        "legID":"12121",
    "message":212112
    },
  {
    "legID":"12122",
    "message":212112
  }
];
var json_src = [
        {
        "legID":"12121",
    "message":212100
    },
  {
    "legID":"12123",
    "message":212112
  }
];

console.log(angular.merge(json_dest, json_src));
```

the output is:

```
[
   {
     "legID":"12121",
     "message":212100
   },
   {
     "legID":"12123",
     "message":212112
   }
]
```

it merged the duplicates
but i am missing the other legID "12123"
i need to know **how** it can be done efficiently ?
and also **why** is it happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angular.merge` is not used to merge arrays but to deeply extend the destination object with enumerable properties of the source object:

> Deeply extends the destination object dst by copying own enumerable properties from the src object(s) to dst. You can specify multiple src objects. If you want to preserve original objects, you can do so by passing an empty object as the target: 
>   `var object = angular.merge({}, object1, object2)` [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge)

If you just want to combine the two arrays into one you don't need an angular API to do that. Simply use concat:

```
json_dest = json_dest.concat(json_src);
```

If you want to remove the duplicates by a certain property, for example legID in your case, you can do that after combining the arrays. There are plenty of resources on how to do that. See for example this question: [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

syntax for merge is

```
var object = angular.merge({}, obj1, obj2);
```

it is showing only second element

try using

```
console.log(angular.merge(dst, src1, src2));
```

Comment: this doesn't works if you mean  
`src1 = json_src` and `src2 = json_dest`   
and dst is a new variable